# Using input redirection, how to read file and get character string in C?

Tags: c++

I have a file that I want my program to read from using input redirection from the command line. For example,`a.out < file.dat` . Then I was going to use `cin.get()` and put characters in an array.

I don't want to hard code any input file names, which I have been seeing in some of the existing posts. If I treat this input redirection as `stdin`, do I have to explicitly open my file?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  string filename;
  ifstream infile;

  cin >> filename;  

  do {               

  int c = 0; 
  c = infile.get();  //need to get one character at a time
                     //further process


} while ( ! infile.eof());
```

}

Comment: Your use of `!infile.eof()` is wrong.

Comment: You don't have to open the file if it's being redirected as stdin input.

Comment: Currently you're trying to read a filename from `cin`.  Just read the actual contents: `char c; while (cin.get(c)) { ... }`  This tests for EOF *immediately after* attempting to read a character, which is how it needs to be done.  The above overload of `get()` returns an `istream&` that will evaluate to false when EOF or any other read error occurs.

Comment: And I guess this works, too. `while (cin.good(c)) { (cin.get(c))...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), which is a stream buffer associated with `stdin`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c;
    while (std::cin.get(c))
    {
        std::cout << c << std::endl; // will print out each character on a new line
    }
    exit(0);
}
```